# Вылетает приложение на моменте InitializeComponent() Xamarin

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin

Здравствуйтею Хотел в приложении сделать добавление человека и вывод его в listview, однако происходит краш вот тут :

```
public partial class PersonPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }
    public PersonPage(MainViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();  //в этой строчке
        ViewModel = vm;
        this.BindingContext = ViewModel;
    }
}
```

С вот таким сообщением:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: void Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.SimpleValueTargetProvider..ctor(object[],object,Xamarin.Forms.Internals.INameScope)

Пытался делать через MVVM. Вот код MainViewModel:

```
public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public Person person { get; private set; }
    PersonsListViewModel pvm;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        person = new Person();
    }

    public PersonsListViewModel ListViewModel
    {
        get { return pvm; }
        set
        {
            if (pvm != value)
            {
                pvm = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ListViewModel");
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name.Trim())) ||
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Surname.Trim())) ||
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Gender.Trim())) ||
                (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DoB.Trim())));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return person.Name; }
        set
        {
            if (person.Name != value)
            {
                person.Name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Surname
    {
        get { return person.Surname; }
        set
        {
            if (person.Surname != value)
            {
                person.Surname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Surname");
            }
        }
    }

    public string DoB
    {
        get { return person.DoB; }
        set
        {
            if (person.DoB != value)
            {
                person.DoB = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DoB");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Gender
    {
        get { return person.Gender; }
        set
        {
            if (person.Gender != value)
            {
                person.Gender = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Gender");
            }
        }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return person.Id; }
        set
        {
            if (person.Id != value)
            {
                person.Id = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Код PersonPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GenTree.ViewModels"
         x:Class="GenTree.Views.PersonPage">

<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout x:Name="personStack">
        <Label Text="Name" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="Surname" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Surname}" FontSize="Medium" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Button Text="Add" Command="{Binding ListViewModel.SavePersonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        <Button Text="Delete" Command="{Binding ListViewModel.DeletePersonCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
        <Button Text="Back" Command="{Binding Path=ListViewModel.BackCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Если что, скажите что ещё скинуть для полной картины. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что за ошибка? (Длинны ради)

Comment: @SeeSharp Unhandled Exception:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: void Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Internals.SimpleValueTargetProvider..ctor(object[],object,Xamarin.Forms.Internals.INameScope)

Comment: На этой строке обычно вылетает при ошибке в View (XAML). Вы уверены в верности вашей разметки? При редактировании не пишет нечего? Мне допустим не нравиться, что не закрыт `<ContentPage>`. Также советую вам убрать указание `DataContext` через разметку.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ он был закрыт, просто я дурачок, не скопировал случайно весь код)) Убрал указание datacontext через разметку. Не помогло(

Comment: @DigitalResistance А вы пробовали просто почистить проект, кэш студии, и сделать ребилд?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не помогло( Может быть проблема в самом переходе на страницу ( типо PushAsync) ?

Comment: @DigitalResistance Тут к сожалению я бессилен. С ксамарином у меня отношения по типу "все трудно", когда я пробовал, эта засранка крашилась при каждом чихе и не было норм визуального редактора)) Сейчас я сужу по WPF. По виду у вас все более менее, вроде. Я бы лично еще посмотрел как поведет себя приложение с пустой страницей,  как поведет себя другой (чистый) проект, а также совпадают ли Namespace у PersonPage и ее Xaml части (но тут обычно даже не собирает проект).

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была решена обновлением Xamarin.forms до версии 4.3 во всех проектах.